Ways to match elements of two sets
Consider this problem:
There are two sets of N elements each, 1 <= N <= 21. I need to pair each element from set #1 to a distinct element of set #2 with restrictions. Input also contains a matrix where the value at row i, column j is 1 if the ith element of set #1 can be matched with the jth element of set #2. If it can't be matched the value is 0. Find how many ways there are to make the N pairs of elements mod 10^9+7.
Example input (first line is N, next N lines are the matrix, one row per line)
3
0 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

Example output
4

Example input:
3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

Example output:
6

I don't know where to start on this one. Trying all possible matching orders will take forever and I could run out of memory. I think it could be dynamic programming. How to solve this?

I removed the C++ tag because this question has nothing to do with C++.

Please read this answer on Meta. Dumping a problem statement and asking how to solve it is not a type of questions we expect here.

@Evg I'm not asking to be taught programming. is it not allowed to ask about algorithm design? this is a specific answerable problem, I don't get what the issue is. if it's too easy, then surely it's easy to just give an answer

There are countless coding puzzles in the Internet. One could dump these puzzles here and ask how to solve them. This is not what SO is for. It is perfectly OK to ask about algorithm design. But you are not asking about design, you're asking to give you a solution. You were writing about DP. Have you tried it? At which step you failed? Please show some effort and ask a real question.

This question is fine.  You just aroused the ire of the folks in the C++ tag because your question isn't about C++.

@Evg this is about designing an algorithm to solve the problem (isn't that what algorithms are for?). or are we just nitpicking on the definition of design? and tbh, if you know how to solve the problem, I do not get why seeing a botched attempt from me would help. you would just be able to answer directly. and when I read other questions when looking for answers, I never care about wrong solutions in the questions, it's just useless text to scroll through

@MattTimmermans thanks, I'll keep that in mind. do you have any ideas for this problem?

What is your reason for including "dynamic programming" as a tag? If you don't know if DP is applicable (I don't believe it is) you should not include it as a tag.

@user25680598 No, I don't have any good ideas about this problem.  It's super hard.  I found a couple papers on the subject (counting perfect matchings in bipartite graphs), but nothing that I could present on SO.

@Unmitigated, thank you for pointing out that I answered a question that had not been asked. That is not the first time have done that, despite my efforts to overcome that particular personality disorder. Perhaps that will become less of a problem as I become older and wiser.

@Unmitigated, I've modified my answer. Though I view my solution as simply a recursive calculation, and not a dynamic programming formulation, I am wondering if that is the sort of thing you had in mind.

Here is a recursive solution. I will provide code in Ruby, which can be viewed as pseudo-code. Before doing so I will present an example which should give the reader an idea of how the recursive calculations will progress.
An example
Suppose the given array were as follows.
maps = [
  [0, 1, 1, 0], # element 0 in group 1
  [1, 0, 1, 0], # element 1 in group 1
  [1, 1, 0, 1], # element 2 in group 1
  [1, 0, 0, 1]  # element 3 in group 1
]

Here maps[i][j] = 1 if element i (base zero) of group 1 can be mapped to element j of group 2 and equals 0 otherwise. For example, element 1 of group  1 can be mapped to elements 0 and 2 of group 2, but not to elements 1 and 3 of group 2.
We process each element of group 1 in turn. Element 0 of group 1 can be assigned to elements 1 and 2 in group 2. The total number of mappings therefore equals tot[1] + tot[2], where tot[j] equals the total number of mappings when the first element of group 1 is mapped to element j of group 2.
To compute tot[1] we modify the array maps to the following:
[
  [1, 0, 1, 0], # element 1 in group 1
  [1, 0, 0, 1], # element 2 in group 1
  [1, 0, 0, 1]  # element 3 in group 1
  #   ↑ zeroed column
]

which is then passed to the recursive method.
Note that column 1 is comprised entirely of zeroes, preventing any of the remaining elements of group 1 from being mapped to element 1 in group 2. The problem described by this array is the same as the original one, suggesting a recursive solution for counting permitted maps.
Continuing in this way we will either reach a point when the first row is all zeroes, in which case zero is returned to the calling method or there will be a single row, corresponding to the last element of group 1 (element 3), with a 1 in one of the columns, and 0's elsewhere. In that case 1 is returned.
Helper method
We first construct a method that strips the first row off the passed maps array and zeroes out the j'th "column".
def remove_first_row_and_zero_col_j(maps, j)
  maps[1..-1].map { |row| row.map.with_index { |e,i| i==j ? 0 : e  } }
end     

The seemingly roundabout way I've done that is to avoid mutating the array maps that has been passed as an argument.
For the example above,
remove_first_row_and_zero_col_j(arr, 1)
  #=> [[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]]
           ↑ column zeroed

and
remove_first_row_and_zero_col_j(arr, 2)
  #=> [[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]]
              ↑ column zeroed

Main method
def count_mappings(maps)
  return maps[0].max if maps.size == 1 # will equal 0 or 1
  first_row = maps[0]
  n = first_row.size
  n.times.sum do |j|
    if first_row[j] == 1
      # assign current group 1 element to element j in group 2
      new_map = remove_first_row_and_zero_col_j(maps, j)
      count_mappings(new_map)
    else
      0
    end
  end
end

Note that I've written this to make the calculations easy to follow, with no concern about efficiency.
Applying the method
count_mappings(maps)
  #=> 3

The three valid mappings in this example are as follows.
0->1
1->2
2->3
3->0

0->2
1->0
2->1
3->3

0->2
1->0
2->1
3->3  


Thanks, I gave you an upvote, but I've tried this idea and it takes too long

You might try a few simple changes that could substantially reduce solution times. For example, as a first step at each level you might swap the first row of the array with the row containing the fewest 1's. Moreover, If in performing that step  a row is found with zero 1's you could return zero to the calling method immediately. Let me know if you wish me to make that change in my answer.
